# Is this the right SQL code to Write In bottonClick event?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm quite new to ADO.NET Database and I have a a requirement where I need to add the sql select code in bottonclick event

---

```
private void BtnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try   
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnStr);
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From Employee =N '" +
              TxtId.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Form1_Load(sender, e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Firs off it looks like you're missing a "WHERE ColumnName".  Second you should really use sql parameters instead of concatenation, then you don't need to worry about sanitizing the input (which that simple replace doesn't completely cover).  Finally for a query you'd want to do `ExecuteReader` and then read the results in and do something with them `ExecuteNonQuery` is for things like a delete, insert, or update.

Comment: Also put the conection, command, and reader into `using` statements so they will be disposed properly

Comment: It seems that I also forget to add employee ID in there(SELECT Eployee ID From Employee) .                                                                                                            Do I still need to use the Text.Replace??

Comment: Thanks for answering my question,really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Correct the select command :

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From Employee"
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you attach the code to the load event of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     string sql = "SELECT* From Employee where EmployeeId = @EmployeeId";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnStr))
            {
                connection.Open;
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeId", TxtId.Text);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Form1_Load(sender, e);
                }
                connection.Close;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: It says the word "connection" in new SqlCommand(sql, connection) does not exist in current context,What should I do?

Comment: IT should work.  The previous code had some issues. Can you please try with the edited one. It  is compiling fine for me